# How to properly make a vertical scrollable area

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I built a simple layout like this:

[image: layout]

**The problem:** I can't scroll the SideBar, and if I try to scroll the entire page scrolls.

The layout has been originally defined in the **GoogleMap.js** using [styled-components](https://styled-components.com/):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import GoogleMapReact from 'google-map-react';
import ShipTracker from '../components/ShipTracker';
import SideBar from '../components/SideBar';

const MapContainer = styled.div`
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 2fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 200px;
    grid-gap: 10px;
    height: 100vh;
    grid-template-areas: "google-map   sidebar" "ship-tracker sidebar";

    .google-map {
        background: #424242;
        grid-area: google-map;
        position: relative;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .map-sidebar {
        background: #9dc183;
        grid-area: sidebar;
    }
    .ship-tracker {
        grid-area: ship-tracker;
    }
`;
```

below a snippet from the **SideBar.js**:
I should mention that this uses the [React Card](https://reactstrap.github.io/components/card/) as the SideBar is going to be populated by a certain number of cards carrying images, description etc:

```
const Sidebar = () => (
    <div className="map-sidebar">
        <Row>
            <Col sm="11">
                <Card className="mb-2">
                    <CardImg />
                    <CardBody>
                        <div>
                            <img src={image} alt="Atchafalaya" />
                        </div>
                        <td />
                        <CardTitle>
                            <h3>Atchafalaya</h3>
                        </CardTitle>
                        <CardText>
                            <h6>Project Details</h6>
                            <p>
                                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer
                                adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa.
                            </p>
                            Trailing Suction Hopper Dredge
                        </CardText>
                        <div class="btn-toolbar">
                            <button type="button" id="btnSubmit" class="btn btn-primary mr-3">
                                Download Project Specs
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </CardBody>
                </Card>
            </Col>
        </Row>
```

And its related **SideBar.css**:

```
html,
body,
.flex-vertical {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
.flex-vertical {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
}
.map-sidebar {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
    flex: 1;
    overflow: hidden;
}
tbody {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    cursor: default;
}
```

**What I have done so far:**

1) I think that the problem could be in the `.css` file and I arrived to the best (so far) configuration I put above. Although I thought that `flex-flow:` is the main parameter to change to have the SideBar scrolling. But it didn;t work.

2) I am not sure if `styled-components` could be the reason for this behavior. The reason why I am saying this is because how the layout was divided happened there. SO I am not sure if the parameter `position:` could be helpful play with.

3) Maybe there is something missing in the `<div className="map-sidebar">` but I cam not sure what could be, if that is the case.

4) Last, I used [React Card](https://reactstrap.github.io/components/card/) as the SideBar is going to be populated by `Cards` containing various information of ships.

Thanks for pointing in the right direction.

Comment: Why are you hiding overflow if you want to see it? Change that to `auto`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting your overflow to "hidden", but instead, you can change it to `overflow-y: scroll;`, so it adds a scrollbar permanently. If you want the scrollbar to only appear when necessary, you can set it to `overflow-y: auto;`.